# Where i can find the official galaxy tab simulator for the android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile, galaxy-tab

All is in the title..., i want to find the galaxy tab add-on for the android-sdk.

I found that : http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9500 but it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only "GALAXY Tab" package in the **Android SDK Manager** is for Android 2.2 (API 8) that Google ships with the Android SDK, and as far as I can tell, it's the same as the one you can download from the link you provided.

I downloaded the package from your link and installed it in my "android-sdk\add-ons"-folder and then started "AVD Manager" and created a new device based on **Target** "GALAXY Tab Addon (Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.) - API Level 8".

Everything seems to work okay for me, see screenshot of the AVD running:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

[SamsungSellerOffice](http://seller.samsungapps.com/) includes real device testing on many samsung devices.